# How to alter the URI in django?

Tags: python, django

http://packages.python.org/django_simple_feedback/ref/request-response.html tells that the absolute URI is built using the server variables available in this request. So, How can I alter the URI using `HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri`.

My situation is:
`/foo/bar/2/`    is the url having corresponding view `load_view(request)` Before rendering the template I want to alter the URI by attaching the new absolute URI in the request. So, that My templte renders on the URL `/foo/`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`django.shortcuts.redirect`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to redirect to a different location:

```
def load_view(request):
    return redirect('/foo/')
```

You will still need a corresponding view setup for that url, of course, as this will cause the user's browser to redirect to `/foo/`. If you want to change the url without refreshing the page, you can do this with HTML5 now:

```
window.history.pushState('','foo','/foo/');
```